# If $A^{-1}=1/\det(A)\cdot B$, then what is $B$ called?

Tags: matrices, terminology

For a $2\times2$ matrix

$$A = \pmatrix{a & b \\ c & d}$$

its inverse can be expressed as

$$ A^{-1} = \frac1{\det(A)} \pmatrix{d & -b \\ -c & a}$$

Obviously $\det$ has a name. Does the matrix $\pmatrix{d & -b \\ -c & a}$ have a name?

Comment: I think it’s called adjugate matrix (that’s what my book called it)
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

Comment: I think "adjugate" is often used (and this is what I would call it), but "classical adjoint" is also often used (or just "adjoint").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called the [Adjugate Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of $A$.